# failed to get a socket / probably libapr1 error

Tags: apache-2.2, debian, redmine

I started configuring my server to use redmine on it.
I tried a lot of approaches and the last one fast to try passenger.

When I run passenger-install-apache2-module It said that I am missing some packages.
After installing some of them I wanted to check how the server works. And I can't restart it.
The message I get is

```
[Thu Aug 01 15:15:22 2013] [crit] (22)Invalid argument: alloc_listener: failed to get a 

socket for x.x.x.x
Syntax error on line 9 of /etc/apache2/ports.conf:
Listen setup failed
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
 failed!
```

the x.x.x.x <- is an actual IP, I just crossed it out.
On the lined 9 of that config is

```
Listen x.x.x.x:80
```

It worked before perfectly.
I read that the solution to this problem is to build libapr1 by myself but I can't do this. I get some missing packages errors and when I try to install them there are more missing packages and the final one is not found by apt-get.

This is the solution I found but I can't execute that code.
[Apache in linux-vserver won't start, can't create socket](https://serverfault.com/questions/496989/apache-in-linux-vserver-wont-start-cant-create-socket)

I am totaly new to this so please ask me anything that can help You understand my problem.

EDIT:
The error was made because the apache server was updated without updating the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

Apache was already running. You must stop the existing server before starting it again.

Comment: But i am RESTARTING, not starting : /
I am afraid to STOP it because I fear that It won't start.

Comment: Restarting means that it stops first, then starts again. So, you MUST do this.

Comment: But I mean that I am using the "restart" comand instead of "stop" and then "start". Sorry if I was misunderstood but english is not my native language.